# Generate Python dictionary from combination of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, combinations

I've tried to solve my issue but I could not.

I have three Python lists:

```
atr = ['a','b','c']
m = ['h','i','j']
func = ['x','y','z']
```

My problem is to generate a Python dictionary based on the combination of those three lists:

The desired output:

```
py_dict = {
    'a': [('x','h'), ('x','i'), ('x','j'), ('y','h'), ('y','i'), ('y','j'),('z','h'), ('z','i'), ('z','j')],
    'b': [('x','h'), ('x','i'), ('x','j'), ('y','h'), ('y','i'), ('y','j'),('z','h'), ('z','i'), ('z','j')],
    'c': [('x','h'), ('x','i'), ('x','j'), ('y','h'), ('y','i'), ('y','j'),('z','h'), ('z','i'), ('z','j')]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
atr = ['a','b','c']
m = ['h','i','j']
func = ['x','y','z']
prod = list(itertools.product(func, m))
result = {i:prod for i in atr}
```

Output:

```
{'a': [('x', 'h'), ('x', 'i'), ('x', 'j'), ('y', 'h'), ('y', 'i'), ('y', 'j'), ('z', 'h'), ('z', 'i'), ('z', 'j')], 'b': [('x', 'h'), ('x', 'i'), ('x', 'j'), ('y', 'h'), ('y', 'i'), ('y', 'j'), ('z', 'h'), ('z', 'i'), ('z', 'j')], 'c': [('x', 'h'), ('x', 'i'), ('x', 'j'), ('y', 'h'), ('y', 'i'), ('y', 'j'), ('z', 'h'), ('z', 'i'), ('z', 'j')]}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, Oh God, I just know if Python has this kind of function.